# Is there any ant killer which is safe for my pets?

Tags: dogs, health, poison, pest-control

I am trying to find very effective and natural ant killer to kill ants inside my house. they are all over, in my kitchen, in my bedroom, windows, main doors. I was tried some ant killers, but they smells so bad. And I have a dog. I do want my get effect with those ant killer. So, I didn't use it any more..please recommend some better ant killer which is safe for my dog.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a bad ant infestation, you need to call an exterminator to come out and treat the inside and outside of your house. Most of the chemicals will be pet safe after a certain amount of time. You can just take your dog and spend the day somewhere else.

If you have areas you really think the pet will get into on a regular basis, like around their food bowl, then you could use diatomaceous earth. This is a natural product that looks like a white powder. It's completely safe for humans an pets. In fact some people feed it to their animals as a natural dewormer, though I have my doubts as to the effectiveness of it in that instance. I've even heard that some people ingest the occasional amount of it for the same purpose, in some places.

The way I understand that it works is that the grains of dust are actually like microscopic little knives. The don't hurt soft creatures like you, your dog, worms, etc..., because the nicks are so small and we heal. However, supposedly any insect with an exoskeleton gets nicked and it cuts their exoskeleton. This causes them to dehydrate because they don't have skin that rapidly seals up. They die of dehydration.

Again, it's a white powder, so it isn't going to stay in high traffic areas for very long, but you can put it down anywhere you want and it's perfectly safe, even if your dog goes and licks it. It will last much longer if it's in places you normally wouldn't disturb, like the back of your dish cabinets, under trim, under your washer and dryer, etc...

I'm pretty sure you can order some online. It's hard for me to get around where I'm at, because the small bags online are more expensive and the bags I can find locally are cheaper, but they want to sell you like 50lbs at a time. It's something you can look into, though, that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think D.E. would work best in this situation but I am offering alternative solutions. For a contact killer you can use dishsoap and water in a spray bottle (I am pretty sure it suffocates them). You can also set a trap where you get a small plate of really shallow soapy water and leave a sugar trail to it (I have not tried this method but supposedly it is good for taking out groups of ants).

If you dont want to kill them lemon juice or orange rinds and water supposedly has a chemical which repels them too. This supposedly works as a preventative thing and a contact thing (but doesnt kill them).

Just putting this out there because i can, but this option is low impact and environmentally safe but not pet safe upon ingestion. Borax or boric acid and sugar mix on a plate (or a cotton ball soaked in the mixture and water) can kill the ants too

Answer (score 0):

Try Dichlorvos strips. You can buy these at most hardware stores and the vapours from the strips affect invertebrates; however, these strips should be used only for a short time and shouldn't be used while you are inhabiting a room (though my people ignore the warnings on the package and do just that.

The CDC notes:

> Do not use in kitchens or food prep or storage areas where unwrapped food may be exposed.  Kitchen utensils should not contact the strips.
>   Pets and children should not play or sleep where strips are in use, nor should the strips be used in any room where humans are likely to spend more than four hours a day. An important sidenote here: most of the illnesses (65%) reported in the CDC paper occurred when exposures exceeded four hours per day.

You can close a room and leave the strip to run it's course overnight and then move the strip somewhere else. Once the strip has been removed, provided that there is some ventilation, there will not be any harmful residue left behind. If you are moving through the room occasionally the vapours won't harm you or your dog. You can keep these strips on your exterior walls (on the outside of your house) to help deter them.

Side Note: I also use diatomaceous earth to kill/deter ants as my wife has a terrible ant phobia.

Answer (score -2):

My advice don't use borax if you have kids and pets inside your home. Borax is harmful for pets. I recommend you to use ant killer spray that is safe for kids and pets. It is 100% natural and non toxic and no smell, no stain. I have been used this ant spray from last year, it is very effective against ants. It is safe for kids and pets that's why I brought it online from. you can find many pets and kids safe ant killer at http://petsafeantkiller.org